# Keeping my Selections when Refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

So I have looked around and there is nothing about storing data collect on a webpage so if I refresh said page it would still have everything I either wrote of selected previously. I would like to implement this feature to my website.

[image]

If I select one of the options is selected, it filters to said option but I want that option to save on my page when website is refreshed. Is there anyway to do so???

Comment: You need to have some state mechanism.
ex: URL or cookies/session
You can also use localStorage

Comment: @OmriLuzon how would I code that? I understand I need some type of localStorage but have no idea on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

First of all you can save it on server, but it to much resource cost and in most situations not good solution.

For this problem the best way to store this info on client. You can use something like cookies, session storage and local storage.
I think session and local storage are the best for your purposes. Difference between them session storage save info for current sessin - browser window, loses after browser window closed. Local storage works for browser at all, loses after cockies and storage clear (by hands). So on current computer and browser local storage would save info until it directly cleared))

Also you can use query string, but it is bad solution.

You can simple find more info about localstorage in the internet. Also popular frameworks like angularjs has services to manage work with local and session storage)

Comment: So what exactly would I write?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achive what you are looking for is with [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which is a feature that is supported on most web browsers.

The API in javascript looks something like this:

```
function onClick(){
  localStorage.setItem('selectedRole', role);
}
```

And on the page load:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    selectedRole = localStorage.getItem('selectedRole')
});
```

You should probably edit the code a bit to fit your needs, This is how I guess you implemented your application.

Comment: I don't want it to save selected champ just the role that has been selected.

Comment: So just change it according to your needs :)

Comment: so should I do 'localStorage.setItem('selectedRole', assassin);

Comment: BTW Im extremely new to this haha

Comment: Preferably put a string literal "assassin" there for example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, sessionStorage is the best choice since you need to persist on refresh only. On page close, the data will lose.

**Store the data on page refresh using:**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem('selectedFilter', selectedFilterData);
};
```

**Retrieve the data on page load using:**

```
window.onload = function () {
  var selectedFilter = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedFilter');
  if(selectedFilter !== null) {
       //set the selections
  }
};
```